# Drools Workbench - multiple repositories

Tags: java, drools, workbench, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

I have multiple repositories on github cloned into my drools workbench. All of the repositories have the same structure but different content in .gdst files. When i create a new .gdst or another file in one workbench, how can i copy/push these files in other workbenches?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure githook in Business Central (Workbench) for any repository.

1. In folder

`$ cd _EAP_HOME_/bin/.niogit/<SPACE>/<PROJECT_NAME>.git/hooks`

2. Create a `post-commit` file that will push your changes to the Github:

`#!/bin/sh`

`git push origin +master`

For more info you can read official [documentation here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.5/html/configuring_business_central_settings_and_properties/managing-business-central-git-hooks-con).